# git rebase --interactive | fails renamed path case

Tags: git, rebase

I try to interactive rebase some commits.
My git-log looks something like this

```
A - Files added  
B - Some commit  
C - Some commit  
D - Renamed path from A (dir/dir/dir => Dir/Dir/Dir)  
E - Some commit  
F - Some commit
```

I can rebase E,F without problems but anything from A-D is impossible to drop, squash, edit.

Error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:  
*** list of files contain the lowercase pathes ***
error: could not detach HEAD
```

Ignore case config value

```
$git config --global core.ignorecase
false
```

Commit from D (there are multiple files)

```
rename from php/software/utils/GlobalManager.php
rename to php/software/Utils/GlobalManager.php
similarity index 100%
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I get along this.

Comment: When you start your rebase, your worktree is clean, right ? and the files+folders on disk match the exact casing of commit `D` ?

Comment: @LeGEC Working dir is clean (rebase would fail instantly). Will add more info to post, see post for part of commit message and yes forlder in dir is similar to the ones in the commit.

Comment: A stupid thing to try : add an extra commit, where you *delete* all the renamed files and dirs, then run `rebase -i`. If it works (or fails), you can always reset to `HEAD~` afterwards.

Comment: @LeGEC Cannot follow you (partially). I have to put the delete commit before commit D right? and then how?    Git rm with thoose pathes fails (at commit G)

Comment: I meant after `F`. The error shows up when you start the interactive rebase, right? when git tries to switch from `F` to `detached A` ?

Comment: @LeGEC Hard to say: git rebase -i HEAD~40 <- my command, it will open up my editor. Anything after D works. If i add a break after D everything works, but before D error

Comment: `git rebase -i` detects if the beginning of the script says "don't change anything", and skips that part (it will not rewrite the commits, you can see the hashes do not change). All your descriptions are consistent with that.

Comment: Not with break, if there is a break anything can happen I could add new commits or do other stuff

Comment: My question was : when you try to act on one of the initial commits, the error appears right away, right ? you don't get to edit `A`, and hit the error when `git` tries to replay `D` ?

Comment: Yeah thats correct it seems as soon as git tries to rollback D everything fails (just checked tried to write edit before A direct failure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stupid thing to try : add an extra commit at the tip of your current branch, where you rename the problematic paths to paths that will not conflict :

```
# from your current HEAD :
git mv php/software/Utils php/software/Utils-wip
# rename other folders if necessary
git commit
```

After that, run your interactive rebase :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~41
```

and see if it works.

Whatever the issue, you can revert the extra commit afterwards :

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
# that or drop the last commit from your `rebase -i` list
```

Comment: Worked *partialy* I now squashed the additional commit you made into D and it resolved, now I can edit that commit and can edit the stuff before that commit. Thank you

Comment: I think the lession from this: If you rename the case, do it in two commits.... confuzius once said

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue i also faced, what i did just revert the rebase **git revert** and follow the below steps agains :-

> git rebase -i Head~3 // no of commit we want to rename

> then change the Pick to reword

```
pick f7f3f6d Change my name a bit
pick 310154e Update README formatting and add blame
pick a5f4a0d Add cat-file
```

like here i want to rename this all the 3 commis so i change the pick prefix to reword

```
reword f7f3f6d Change my name a bit
reword 310154e Update README formatting and add blame
reword a5f4a0d Add cat-file
```

and then save continue :wq!.

then one by one all the commits will rebase , you will be prompt with commit message name edit and there you can change the name of the commit.if there is any conflict just add and run **git commit --ammend**.

so these commit message rename window will prompt to you is equal to number of commit name you want to change. that's how you can change the name of the commits.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right solution but it worked for me:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
...
error: could not detach HEAD
```

so I did:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~
$ git commit --amend
```

It worked, the 2 commit are squashed into 1

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I Git Removed the file with the initial name that it had. My problem was I renamed `abcFile.py` to `ABCFile.py`. So when I got that error message, I knew I wanted to keep `ABCFile.py` so I did this command.

```
git rm `path/to/abcFile.py`
```

Git has some gotchas when working with naming/renaming files with only the casing changed.